# How can I list all Github users with V3 APIs?

Tags: ruby, api, curl, github, github-api

I can get just the first 100 users :

```
lsoave@ubuntu:~$ curl -i https://api.github.com/users|grep -c login
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  104k  100  104k    0     0  92808      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  100k
100
lsoave@ubuntu:~$
```

but I need the full list and /users?page= ( where n goes from 0 to **∞** )  get the same 100 user list :

```
lsoave@ubuntu:~$ curl -i https://api.github.com/users?page=0 | grep login | tail -10
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  104k  100  104k    0     0  90797      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  101k
    "login": "danielharan",
    "login": "kvnsmth",
    "login": "collectiveidea",
    "login": "canadaduane",
    "login": "nate",
    "login": "dstrelau",
    "login": "sunny",
    "login": "dkubb",
    "login": "jnicklas",
    "login": "richcollins",

lsoave@ubuntu:~$ curl -i https://api.github.com/users?page=1 | grep login | tail -10
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  104k  100  104k    0     0    99k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  110k
    "login": "danielharan",
    "login": "kvnsmth",
    "login": "collectiveidea",
    "login": "canadaduane",
    "login": "nate",
    "login": "dstrelau",
    "login": "sunny",
    "login": "dkubb",
    "login": "jnicklas",
    "login": "richcollins",

lsoave@ubuntu:~$ curl -i https://api.github.com/users?page=2 | grep login | tail -10
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  104k  100  104k    0     0  95960      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  104k
    "login": "danielharan",
    "login": "kvnsmth",
    "login": "collectiveidea",
    "login": "canadaduane",
    "login": "nate",
    "login": "dstrelau",
    "login": "sunny",
    "login": "dkubb",
    "login": "jnicklas",
    "login": "richcollins",

lsoave@ubuntu:~$ curl -i https://api.github.com/users?page=3 | grep login | tail -10
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  104k  100  104k    0     0    99k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  110k
    "login": "danielharan",
    "login": "kvnsmth",
    "login": "collectiveidea",
    "login": "canadaduane",
    "login": "nate",
    "login": "dstrelau",
    "login": "sunny",
    "login": "dkubb",
    "login": "jnicklas",
    "login": "richcollins",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `since` parameter instead of page

Ideally, you get the `id` of the last user on the list (in this case it's **135**) and you make the next call with that id and the new response will contain the users exceeding that userid

```
https://api.github.com/users?since=135
```

Comment: wow, that's great, I wasn't able to find out that in V3 API docs, may I ask you where did you find that ? ... it works great !

Comment: It's actually the at the very bottom of the users method docs :)